# неинициализрованная память

Tags: c++

Я хочу написать функцию по умножению чисел (длинная арифметика) , застрял в этом моменте : вроде все правильно проинициализировал , конкретно сделал под умножение 12*20 ,но почему то компилятор ругается на неинициализированную память в 55 строчке . Может это ли быть баг visual studio , или все таки есть какая то ошибка с моей стороны , спасибо заранее

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

void Multiplication(char A[], char B[], char C[], int& max, int size_digit_A, int size_digit_B)
{
    
    
    //12*20
        C[0] += A[0] * B[0];
        C[1] += A[1] * B[0];

        C[1] += A[0] * B[1];
        C[2] += A[1] * B[1];
        
}
int main()
{
    string digit_A;
    string digit_B;

    char A[300], B[300], C[300];
    
    int size_digit_A, size_digit_B;
    int max,length;
    
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_A;
    system("cls");
    
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> digit_B;
    system("cls");
    
    size_digit_A = digit_A.size();
    size_digit_B = digit_B.size();
    (size_digit_A > size_digit_B) ? (max = size_digit_A) : (max = size_digit_B);
    
    for (int i = max - 1; i >= 0; i--)//здесь правильно
    {
        A[max - i - 1] = digit_A[i];
        B[max - i - 1] = digit_B[i];
    }
    
    cout <<"max"<< max << endl;
    cout << "size_digit_A" << size_digit_A << endl;
    cout << "size_digit_B" << size_digit_B << endl;

    /*for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        A[i] -= '0';
        B[i] -= '0';
        C[i] = 0;
    }*/
    A[1] -= '0'; B[1] -= '0';//компилятор ругается на непроинициализированную память
    A[0] -= '0'; B[0] -= '0';
    Multiplication(A, B, C, max, size_digit_A, size_digit_B);
    
    C[2] += '0';
    C[1] += '0';
    C[0] += '0';
    
    cout << C[2] << C[1] << C[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот все, что дает Visual C++ 2019: `test.cpp(5): warning C4100: size_digit_B: неиспользованный формальный параметр
test.cpp(5): warning C4100: size_digit_A: неиспользованный формальный параметр
test.cpp(5): warning C4100: max: неиспользованный формальный параметр
test.cpp(35): warning C4267: =: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
test.cpp(36): warning C4267: =: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
test.cpp(25): warning C4101: length: неиспользованная локальная переменная` Вашего не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо , видимо действительно вижак тупит , а вы когда вводите числа 12 и 20 у вас выводит 240 ?(у меня вообще какой то мусор потипу №^ и тд , у меня тоже 2019 года )

Comment: Я ничего не вводил и не выводил :) Попробовал - вывел `24@`

Comment: а может вводились однозначные числа?